# Android Copy original source Class to custom Class

Tags: java, android, android-framelayout, viewgroup

I am having a bug in my application which i am unable to track down. I need to dive into the ViewGroup class and alter code in order to track down my issue.
So to make my life easier i would like to temporary 
create a custom `FrameLayout` and a custom `ViewGroup` class.

Now when i create a class called `FrameLayoutCustom` and copy all the original FrameLayout contents to it, it is complaining about missing symbols:

```
Error:(364, 46) error: cannot find symbol class ViewHierarchyEncoder
Error:(40, 31) error: cannot find symbol class NonNull
```

Is there a way to ignore these errors during compilation, because when i inspect the source itself it is also missing there.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on java class file by expanding package which you need to backup and select java class and click copy and then paste in same package, change the name of newly pasted java class then you can do any change to your original java file for debug.

Comment: Yes, but the compiler is complaining about missing symbols.
When i open the original source file it is also complaining about missing symbols. somehow the compiler is ignoring those